# Ionic Cordova Platform errors

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, view

I just tried uploading my App to Ionic View and noticed, the app is almost Blank on Ionic View. Only Input fields, Missing images, Buttons etc. The source of the problem is probably the cordova plaform.

My situation: 
When I tried to add platforms using cordova platform add ios/android
When I did that I got an error saying Platform is already added.

This is where it gets weird. When I try to remove the platform and add it again like this:
Cordova Platform rm ios 
Cordova Platform rm android
Cordova Platform add ios
Cordova Platform add andoird
I still get the error platform is already added.

Someone had the same problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a new dummy project and add platform in that if error is same then let me know.

Comment: @sunielkalwani even if this is an actual solution, it will be good if you could please elaborate it with a valid reason for 'why this solution works?'... It will help other developers to understand it.